# Android: settings all items to the same layout height in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view which is rendered each time with a different list of items, with variable height.
What I want is to set all the `Views` in the list view to the same layout height according to the view with the highest `layout_height`, when setting it to `layout_height="wrap_content"` for each View.

Also I would like to apply min and max values for the height.
So if I define `min=30dp`,`max=100dp`, and the biggest View is automatically rendered with 70dp
all `Views` in the `ListView` should be set to 70dp.

I have no idea how to go about it, expect for calculating in the code the max view height values, and setting them to all views, but this doesn't seem very elegant to me, especially as I need to translate it to DPs in the code.

Any simpler ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your right what you try to achieve wont be as pretty as the regular way, but it'll work ;) usually you would decide height beforehand and then go with it :)